# References and Copies inside of Java regarding to lists

Tags: java, list, reference, copy

Let's say I have a list of objects called "Node" inside of this -> Iterable allNodes.

Let's say I iterated through all the nodes in allNodes and added them to its own list like so:

```
Iterable<Node> allNodes = dataManager.getAllNodes();
List<Node> copyOfAllNodes;
for(Node node : allNodes) {
    copyOfAllNodes.add(node);
}
```

Does the copy become a reference or is it a copy that doesn't affect the original list?

Comment: suppose you don't know (which you should!), is it that difficult to test ?

Comment: Touche sir, you are correct i definitely should have tested it myself to see if it is or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will become just a reference. When you perform:

```
copyAllNodes.add(node)
```

You are inserint `node` that is an object into `copyAllNodes`.

If you want a copy of the object you have other approaches. One of the approaches could be `close`, that is basically implement the `Cloneable` interface and expose `clone` method in order to copy the object, so you could do something like:

```
copyAllNodes.add(node.clone)
```

And this would be a copy that you could modify without any reflection on the copied object. *Is good to remember that the default clone method does just a shallow copy of the object*.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

> The method clone for class Object performs a specific cloning
>   operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the
>   interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown. Note
>   that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable.
>   Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this
>   object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the
>   corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents
>   of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a
>   "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

Comment: Thank you for making that clear, I am usually coding in C++ so I was a bit confused on what was happening.